# Does "heavy ... but restorative" describe a food which is healthy but not for weak people?

Tags: word-choice

> Would you like to eat breakfast?
>
> No, last night I eate a lot. I ate spinach as dinner. It was **heavy** but it is generally a **restorative** dish; not for those who are in restoration but for an ordinary, normal man like me.

I am pretty sure the choicee of the word **heavy** is correct here. But my concern has to do with the word **restorative** . We usually refer to a medicine or tonic that rebalances you as a restorative. What word should we use instead of it when talking about a good and healty food that is restorative but not for weak people? I mean spinach can give you additional strengh as a normal person. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the source?

Comment: I just wrote it by myself.

Comment: then the sentence is weird... come up with some alternative or words that are *clearer*. BTW, in health science, if you say 'restorative' you *should* explain 'what gets restored!' as well!

Comment: I would not call spinach a heavy dish.  Heavy to me implies a large meal high in fat and protein.

Comment: I agree with ssav, "heavy" at least in American English, is usually reserved for high-fat/high-carbohydrate meals, often with a protein.  And spinach, unmodified, wouldn't be referred to as a "dish"; you must add something to indicate the manner of preparation, e.g. "creamed spinach", "boiled spinach". Then it becomes a dish.  In AmE, we usually call foods that are good for you "healthy" foods, meaning 'health-sustaining' or 'conducive to health'.

Comment: A word I might use for spinach is 'nutritious'.  The idea that nutritious food isn't good for weak people makes no sense though.  Is there some kind of cultural misunderstanding going on here?

Comment: On another point: people are not normally described as "in restoration". I have an idea what you mean, but this isn't a typical phrase.

Answer (score -1):

First off, a restorative isn't necessarily used for a tonic or medicine. You can also use it for anything that makes you feel healthier or stronger. You can use the word  as an adjective or noun. Spinach may be restorative to some people and may not be so for others.

For weak people, you can say soft healthy or wholesome food. Even I don't think there's anything wrong grammatically with the phrase soft restorative food, though it sounds  a bit weird.